# How to add an image outside a uitableviewcell

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uiimage

Everywhere people are asking how to add an image inside an Uitableview. Well, I want the opposite, how can I make the cell shorter and add an image in front of it ?
Just like the whatsapp-group-info-screen. (see image)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recommendation with the `tableHeaderView` is valid. But if you already create a view that looks like in image with a "cell" beside it (with the rounded corners of grouped table view), you could also use this view to subclass `UITableViewCell` and thus use this pattern anywhere in your table.

Comment: So make à view with an image and à cell and use it as a headerview?

Comment: No. This would be an extension of your requirements.

Comment: Though I think Whatsapp has solved this in another way.. The sectiontitle is at the time height with the picture.. So you think an image, a sectiontitle and a cell are all put in one cell?

Answer (score 5):

Use `tableHeaderView` property of `UITableView` for this purpose if header is the only place this image will appear. Simply create a `UIView` with the layout you need and set it as tableHeaderView of your tableView.

BTW, you might want to filter the content you're posting in your questions on stackoverflow in the future.

Comment: Isn't the tableHeaderView always above the first cell/section ? 
I would like it next to the first/2nd cell. Or maybe I can add an image next to a sectiontitle ?

Comment: `tableHeaderView` is always above the first section. If need it to act like a `UITableViewCell` then you need to create a custom subclass of `UITableViewCell` and work with it, there are no default means to get the behavior you need.

Comment: So how do i get The image next to the first cell? Or is the only way, Mundi's way?